# How to format buttons in RelativeLayout to be aligned to the center

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, button, android-relativelayout

I want to have two buttons that span from either side of the screen (with a small margin) to the center of the app.

I had hoped that

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

would work the same if I typed

```
android:layout_alignParentcenter="true"
```

but it does not work the same.

Here is my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cath"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cmhs"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cmhs"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mhsdir"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:text="@string/cath"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cfeel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sclose"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cath"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cath"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:text="@string/cfeel"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mhshome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/mhsdir"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mhsdir"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mhshome"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:text="@string/webclo"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/weblink"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/webclo"
        style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cmhs"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:text="@string/mhshome"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pp"
        style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cmhs"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cmhs"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webclo"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:text="@string/pp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mhsdir"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/phonenum"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cmhs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sclose"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sclose"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:text="@string/callmhs"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sclose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cmhs"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:text="@string/sclose"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/school"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ath"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ath"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cfeel"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cfeel"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:text="@string/school"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ath"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sclose"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sclose"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:text="@string/ath"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/school"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="@string/cal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would include a picture but I do not have enough rep...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want both `Button`s to take up 50% of the screen, you can put them in a `LinearLayout` and give them each the same `weight`. Something like

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
>
    <Button
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If this isn't what you want then please clarify.

**Edit**

If you want space in between the two `Button`s then you can create an empty `View` between the `Button`s and give it a `layout_weight` of maybe .5 then 1 for each of the `Button`s. You can do the same thing if you want space on each side of the `Button`s.

Comment: It seems like changing to LinearLayout is the best way to go on this... The app is complete minus the button size so I was just looking for a fix that would not require a rearrangement of the whole layout. Is it easy to change from relative to linear?

Comment: You can use `RelativeLayout` for your root `ViewGroup` still if you need for the placement but wrap the rest in `LinearLayout`s. Depends what will best work for you. There are other ways but I think this is the most efficient if I get what you want.

Comment: This is what I want, but with buttons that almost meet each other in the center. Here is what I have now http://imgur.com/30AHZDi

Never mind I understand what you're saying I will try that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have edited. See if that works for you. You may have to play with the `weight`s some to get precisely what you want.